# How to split csv files into two files based on Colum value in Windows?

Tags: batch-file

I have below records in the source csv file and need to split into two files based on Column A using windows `cmd`.

**Input:**

> ```
> 4000,XXX,X11
> 1000,YYY,Y11
> 3000,ZZZ,Z11
> 4300,XXX,X12
> ```

**Output:**

File 1: (File 1 should be based on the column A where the values are starting with `4`. Ex - `4000` and `4300`)

> ```
> 4000,XXX,X11
> 4300,XXX,X12
> ```

File 2: Other records.

> ```
> 1000,YYY,Y11
> 3000,ZZZ,Z11
> ```

Comment: I tried with below script. But it not splitting based on the colume.    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /F "delims=," %%a in (Source.csv) do (
    set line=%%a
    set line=!line:,,=, ,!
    set line=!line:,,=, ,!
    for /F "tokens=1 delims=," %%i in (^"!line!^") do (
        echo %%i>>Final.csv
    )
)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

get all lines starting with "4":

```
findstr /b "4" oldfile.csv>four.csv
```

get all lines not starting with "4":

```
findstr /v /b "4" oldfile.csv>rest.csv
```

**edit** to work with second column:

```
findstr /R /B ".*,4" oldfile.csv >four.csv
findstr /R /B /V ".*,4" oldfile.csv >rest.csv
```

Note: as aschipfl mentioned, it might be better to build a `for` loop, but that's more Code.

Comment: How can i split the file If the data is comming in other columns? EX: XXX, 4000, X11

Comment: please give a real example to get a working solution. Which other column? the second? Is there a space after the comma? (reliable?)

Comment: @AravindhK, take a look at `for /F` -- type `for /?` in command prompt and read the help text carefully...

Comment: @aschipfl also possible without `for`. `findstr /R` should do the job (depends on the data)

Comment: I agree, @Stephan, `findstr` is also possible (I don't like it that much though because it has got several [bugs](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8844868/5047996)); but I think `for /F "delims=,"` is just perfect for CSV-files (as long as there are no quoted values which contain `,` themselves; but `findstr` cannot handle such correctly either);

Comment: @Stephen:  I may get the source file as "XXX,4000,X11" (delimited by Comma and there are no spaces. How can I split the file based on second column? 4000 - Company code. The file may contains multiple company code and i need to split the file based on company codes .